# Convert Java While Loop to Multithreaded Loop

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a List say having login names, based on list content, i am processing other methods like :

```
while ( it.hasNext() )
{
   method1();
}
```

Rather than waiting for sequence, since these tasks are independent, i want to run them parallel.

I did following :

```
 ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
 final List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

 while ( it.hasNext() )
    {
        Future<?> future = service.submit(() -> {
                  method1(it.next());
           });
        futures.add(future);
    }
```

But the issue this, it is executing method1 for one loginName 5 times... but i want 5 threads executing the method1 independently. where i am doing it wrong?

TIA!!

Comment: You need to gather the information into memory (I'm assuming this iterator is a `ResultSet`? regardless...), then provide it to some form of threaded execution. As it is now, the scheduled task is the code which is calling `it#next`, which means that it won't actually call it until the task is executed, essentially breaking the entire point behind the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the iterated value first.

```java
final <class> nextItem = it.next();
Future<?> future = service.submit(() -> { method1(nextItem); });
futures.add(future);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not thread safe.
`it.hasNext()` is invoked at each iteration so you could believe getting the expected result but `Iterator` is not thread safe. So if multiple `Callable`s are concurrently executed, you have an unpredictable result with the Iterator use.

Using Thread or Callable is of course possible to take advantage of parallelism but you will need to add explicit synchronization when the iterator is used.
While using`Callable` with explicit synchronizations is in a some way annoying.

As alternative you can use a collection that ensures the thread safety such as `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. For example wrap the original list in the `CopyOnWriteArrayList` copy constructor such as :

```
List<Foo> copyList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(list);
```

Or you could also more simply use a parallel stream that will make your code much less verbose but it is less configurable about the the thread pool under the hood (in some cases, it matters) :

```
list.parallelStream().forEachOrdered(this::method1);
```

Answer (score 0):

> where i am doing it wrong?

You've got a thread that's doing this:

```
while ( it.hasNext() ) {
    Future<?> future = service.submit(...task...);
    futures.add(future);
}
```

That thread keeps calling `it.hasNext()`, but it never calls `it.next()`.

You've got *other* threads (the thread pool's workers) calling `it.next()` but those threads run independently of the loop.  If the time needed for the loop to submit a task to the executor service and add a future to the list is less than the time needed for a worker thread to pick and perform a task, then the loop will get ahead of the executor service, and it will submit more tasks than you intended.